# How does Maven orders the dependency jars on the classpath when using Maven-Jar-plugin with "addClasspath" property true?

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I am trying to understand the way maven orders all the dependency defined in the pom, while we are trying to create a jar using maven-jar-plugin.

I am trying to use manual configuration approach defined [here](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven).

Let's say we have following dependency tree:

- A.1 -> B.1 -> C.1
- D.1 -> E.1
- E.2
- F.1 -> B.2

What will be the eventual classpath created in manifest file?

Comment: It is dangerous to rely on classpath order. Try to avoid that.

Comment: But there must be some logic/algo that maven uses while building it ?

Comment: There is. But I don't know if it is documented. You can find out practically by calling `dependency:list ` on the project. Nevertheless, I would try to create your program in a way that it works for any order of the classpath.